# Applescript in Excel to find a value and then look for another value in the same row

Tags: excel, find, applescript, lookup

This sounds simple enough (and I am sure it is) but I cannot figure out how to do this:
I have data in a table in excel - let's say two columns: Column A contains ID's and Column B contains email addresses.

I am looking for an Applescript that will open up the database file and lookup the ID in the one column but return the value of the second column for me to use later in the rest of the script.

This is what I have thus far:

```
set theFile to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Choose File to Operate on")
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
open theFile
set searchRange to range ("A1:D2")
try
    set foundRange to find searchRange what "ID1" with match case
    (* do something with the foundRange *)
on error -- not found
    (* do error handling *)
end try
end tell
```

Not sure how to get the to the second column and return that value to ie. set to IDEmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set searchRange to range ("A1:A5")
    set foundRange to find searchRange what "ID3" with match case
    set fRow to first row index of foundRange
    set myData to value of range ("B" & fRow as text)
    (* do something with the foundRange *)
end tell
```

[image]